# IQR outlier in R

Tags: r

I am supposed to use the 1.5*IQR rule to determine outliers on the left and right tail by using these two equations in a function:

- Q1-(1.5*IQR)
- Q3+(1.5*IQR)

This is what I have tried so far:

```html
IQR.outliers <- function(x) {
  if(any(is.na(x)))
    stop("x is missing values")
  if(!is.numeric(x))
    stop("x is not numeric")
  Q3<-quantile(x,0.75)
  Q1<-quantile(x,0.25)
  IQR<-(Q3-Q1)
  left<-x<(Q1-(1.5*IQR))
  right<-x>(Q3+(1.5*IQR))
  c(left,right)
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want a vector that flags an observation is its an outlier on either side?

Comment: Also, note that the boxplot function identifies these points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment you are getting a vector of logicals. Instead use logical indexing. Assuming you just want the values themselves and not their positions, then:

```
IQR.outliers <- function(x) {
  if(any(is.na(x)))
    stop("x is missing values")
  if(!is.numeric(x))
    stop("x is not numeric")
  Q3<-quantile(x,0.75)
  Q1<-quantile(x,0.25)
  IQR<-(Q3-Q1)
  left<- (Q1-(1.5*IQR))
  right<- (Q3+(1.5*IQR))
  c(x[x <left],x[x>right])
}
```

Check to see if it gives sensible results:

```
> IQR.outliers (1:100)
integer(0)
> IQR.outliers (c(1:100,1000))
[1] 1000
> IQR.outliers (rnorm(1000) )
[1] -3.522064 -3.296682  2.910200  2.671333
```